# Is it possible to bind dynamic texture samplers to a shader in DX12?

Tags: shader, directx12, memory

So usually texture samplers are set directly in the `D3D12_ROOT_SIGNATURE_DESC` structure in DX12, at least that's how I've been setting them. I was wondering if it's possible to put them in an upload_heap and map a CPU pointer to it or something similar to make it possible to modify the samplers dynamicaly?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible by putting Samplers in descriptor tables to dynamically assign and index into them. Source: https://youtu.be/Wbnw87tYqVg?t=754

Here's an example that uses the HLSL root signature syntax to do this here:
https://youtu.be/Wbnw87tYqVg?t=5277

Comment: Can you put the examples in the answer itself, rather than as video links?